# LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Activity()) - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I'm building an android app which using a map fragment.
Lately I redesigned my app and moved the map view to a fragment.
everything worked before, I'm asking for permissions and manifest has the parent activity of the current fragment.

While I'm trying to get fused location provider as following:

```
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        mFusedLocationClient = 
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Activity())
    }
```

I'm getting:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: android.billboapp.billbo, PID: 8859
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:122)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@20.0.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@20.0.0:1)
> at android.billboapp.billbo.fragments.bottom_nav.BillboardsMapFragment.onMapReady(BillboardsMapFragment.kt:157)
> at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzat.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:5)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:3)
> at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
> at em.bc(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413081@22.24.13 (150400-0):2)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413081@22.24.13 (150400-0):1)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)

my fragment layout is:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.bottom_nav.BillboardsMapFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="50"
    android:src="@drawable/billbo_first_logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_on_map" />
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `Activity()`? Did you try instantiating Activity yourself ? Do not do this, instead use activity or application context.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Activity())
```

to:

```
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
```